# Total a natural number with real number by php?

Tags: php

How can increase a number according to percent with PHP?

For example: `100 + 20% = 120` or `1367 + 33% = 1818.11`

If output was this: **1818.11** i want only this: **1818** or this **12.32 = 12** or **546.98 = 546**

How is it?

Comment: Isnt this basic math? use a fraction. 100 + 100*(20/100) = 120

Comment: How is for this: `1367 + 33% = 1818.11`

Comment: @JimBo - It's not correct. % in PHP is the modulus operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're looking for something deeper, but the answer seems fairly straightforward...

```
$increasedValue = floor( $value * ( 1 + ( $percentageIncrease / 100 ) ) );
```

If you wrapped that in a function, say `increaseByPercentage( $value, $percentageIncrease )`, you would get...

```
increaseByPercentage( 100, 20 ); //returns 120
increaseByPercentage( 1367, 33 ); //returns 1818
```

*Edit*
Based on your comment, I'm not sure what else you are looking for.  [PHP has 6 arithmetic operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

- **Negation (-$a)**
  -5 = -5
- **Addition ($a + $b)**
  5 + 3 = 8
- **Subtraction ($a - $b)**
  5 - 3 = 2
- **Multiplication ($a * $b)**
  5 * 3 = 15
- **Division ($a / $b)**
  5 / 3 = 1.667
- **Modulus ($a % $b)**
  5 % 3 = 2

If you write a line of code that says `$a = 100 + 20%;` it will not parse.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addPercent($number, $percent) 
{
    return (int)($number+$number*($percent/100));
}
echo addPercent(1367, 33); // 1818
```

Just cast the result into an Integer.

Comment: How is this `1367 + 33% = 1818.11` with PHP?

Comment: Don't undestand what you're saying? It's just math.

Comment: @JimBo `(int)'33%'` or `$var = (int)$var` in your case. :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My method isn't quite right. It looks like Farray has outlined a better one as well.

---

Is this what you want?

```
round( 156 + 156 * ( 20/100 ) )
```

Normally without `round()` this would = 187.2. With `round()`, it's equal to 187.

Comment: need to use `floor()` to get what he's looking for.  Example "546.98 = 546" would round to 547

Comment: @JimBo how about not adding the sign in the first place? (See your last question)

Comment: @Jimbo Is the problem here that you're not generating the 20% value yourself, and so by the time you need to operate with it, you need to reformat your '20%' to '20' so you can use it?